# Accessing hidden directories in Linux using Perl

Tags: perl

I am trying to access the hidden `.thunderbird` directory using Perl.

The line `opendir(DIR, $pathname) or die $!` gives me an error

```
No such file or directory
```

How do I access it using Perl?

Comment: Then you are giving the wrong `$pathname`, probably just by running the script from somewhere that isn't your `$HOME`

Comment: Please show how you have defined `$pathname`?

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
opendir(DIR, $ENV{'HOME'}.'/.thunderbird');
```

`$ENV{'HOME'}` accesses the `HOME` environment variable in Linux which usually contains the user's home directory.

String concatenation in Perl is typically done with `.` or [join()](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/join.html) or double-quotes interpolation.

Comment: You have no reason to think that `.thunderbird` is within the `HOME` directory, or that the current working directory isn't `HOME`. Concatenating file path elements should be done using [`File::Spec`](https://metacpan.org/module/File::Spec)

Comment: Rumor has it most user-level config and caching dot directories for various applications are in $HOME. And, there's ~25 of them in my $HOME. But that doesn't guarantee finding it.  Thus the word `try`